# Who were these characters Kenobi walks by in the hallway?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In the fourth episode of the *Obi-Wan Kenobi* TV series,

> Obi-Wan infiltrated Fortress Inquisitorius and discovered a number of deceased Jedi.
>   
>  [image: Composite image of Obi-Wan observing 6 different beings in sepia-tinted windows against a dark grey corridor.]

Who were they?

> The first one looked like Tera Sinube to me, but I don't know about the others.

Comment: The little one looks like https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/J._K._Burtola

Comment: I was watching the episode going "Am I supposed to be recognizing these characters?????".  It seemed like it was a gratuitous scene meant for someone else.

Answer (score 16):

The top left one looks like Tera Sinube, from the Clone Wars series.

They're a jedi master who was training younglings in the temple, and assisted Ahsoka with an investigation.  There isn't any further information on them that I'm aware of, as they don't appear to have been in any material outside of one short story arc in that series.

Picture of Tera Sinube from Clone Wars fandom wiki:
[image: Tera Sinube]

Comment: There's official confirmation that it's Tera Sinube: https://www.starwars.com/obi-wan-kenobi-part-iv-trivia-gallery

Answer (score 13):

Not a complete answer, but the one on the bottom right I assumed it was one of the younglings in the Order 66 scene at the beginning of Episode 1.  Based on the color of the robes and the skin tone, I think it might be the on I highlighted in green.  But given the contrast, it is hard to tell conclusively.

[image]

Comment: That's a good call. I was wondering whether any of those younglings would show up again... I was kinda hoping it would be in a more positive scene.

Comment: @F1Krazy - fandom speculation is leaning heavily that Reva is the youngling in the middle

Comment: I almost asked, don’t you mean Episode III? :)

Comment: @F1Krazy Well, as we've seen in multiple Star Wars outings, including this one, "floating in liquid" does not *necessarily* equate to "dead".  I'm not sure why the Empire would waste so much space just on a trophy case for dead Jedi (especially a random youngling, I mean, come on.)  My guess is this is actually part of how they brainwash and convert captured Jedi into Inquisitors like Reva to hunt down other Jedi.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The rebels cartoon did have a dead jedi being used as bait.  There's potentially some Sith necromancy and cloning in store for these bodies.  https://youtu.be/kJKVoRYB7pE

Comment: @NKCampbell Part V confirms it.

Answer (score 3):

These characters are partially identified by the upcoming Canon reference book [*Dawn of Rebellion: The Visual Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Dawn_of_Rebellion_The_Visual_Guide):

[image: Section from Dawn of Rebellion called "Jedi Tomb"]

> #### JEDI TOMB
>
> In the depths of the fortress is a tomb filled with bodies of captive Jedi, preserved in amber. Youngling **Faris** still wears his training helmet from the night the Temple was attacked, and Jedi **Tera Sinube**, a master since the High Republic, appears to have never let his robes go either.
>
> ##### JEDI EXPOSED
>
> **Velerie Tide** hid her identity following the Great Jedi Purge, blending in with the locals on Athio III, but was captured after being revealed as a Force user.
>
> <sub>([*Dawn of Rebellion: The Visual Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Dawn_of_Rebellion_The_Visual_Guide), via https://www.starwars.com/news/sdcc-2023-lucasfilm-publishing-panel; emphasis added)</sub>

The upper right, middle left, and lower left Jedi from the image in the question remain unidentified.